# Can two PWA:s share the same service worker?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, manifest.json

I want to PWAs to share the same service worker. Since the scope for a PWA and dito for a service worker are defined independently this seems possible. But maybe there is something else that prevents it?